# Pass prop in input type file

Tags: reactjs, input, axios

I'm trying to implement a dowload and upload of files in react js. I'm having a problem taking a prop that I need.

```html
<input
  className="inputfile"
  type="file"
  id="file"
  name="file"
  onChange={event =>
    this.handleUploadFile(event, numeroOfferta)
  }
/>
<label for="file">
  <i class="fa fa-upload" /> Carica File
</label>
```

Here I call the method that handle the data received from the input, in the end it calls axios and i make a simple GET call.

```js
handleUploadFile = (event, numeroOfferta) => {
    let file = new FormData();
    file.append("file", event.target.files[0]);
    console.log(file);
    let name = event.target.files[0];
    //calling async Promise and handling response or error situation

    if (file === null) {
      toast("scegli un file");
    } else {
      this.props.uploadTemplate(file, numeroOfferta, name);
    }
  };
```

After Render I call all the props so I can use them without writing this.props everytime. the props come from App.js and i receive them an array that i populate with a axios Get call to the backend(which is spring JPA) that takes the data from the database.

```js
 let {
      id,
      numeroOfferta,
      accordo,
      commerciale,
      rifOffertaEsterno,
      figureList,
      descrizione,
      tipoOfferta,
      statoOfferta,
      dataInizio,
      dataFine,
      delivery,
      dataEmissione,
      revisione,
      cliente,
      portafoglio,
      imponibileTotale,
      sconto
      // giorniTotali
    } = this.props.offerta;
```

As you can see on change I call a method that send to the axios call the props I need. The event is always right but I need to download or upload a file from a folder that has the name that I want. When I try to take the "numeroOfferta", that is a number, react takes the value of the first line of the table(I open a modal that has the id with the numeroOfferta so i can take all the props of that line). I have this problem only in the input type file.

Thank you for every answer.

Comment: Please include your code in text format in your question instead of linking to external images.

Comment: just done, sorry  :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include more of the context around the example you have shown. If the problem is that `numeraOfferta` is always the first value of a table, you should show the code where `numeraOfferta` is initialized. If it comes from a prop, also show the next component up so that others can help you trace the problem. From your explanation it sounds like this code is in a loop and the issue is likely where the loop is.

Comment: Sorry it's my first question ;). I will include more code in the next minutes. I take numeroOfferta from the props but it work because if I pass it to a button or a input text or everything else it works. I can take the value, the problem is in the input type file where the method is unable to take the value of numeroOfferta for that specific modal with that specific numeroOfferta(I show a lot of things in that modal and everything works right).